How to interpret a mathematical statement involving an inequality $(\leq)$ and an arrow $(\rightarrow)$?
I have the following statement:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(|C_d(G)|<(1-\delta){n\choose 2}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\textrm{Bin}(cn,\delta)\leq dn-{{d+1}\choose 2}\right)\rightarrow 0$$
For readability, I've abstracted away the details about the probability events and written the statement as, $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)\rightarrow0$, where $A$ and $B$ are as in the above equation. My question is about how to interpret the $\leq$ and the $\rightarrow$ symbols. As in, which one bounds tighter? But also, how do I even read it after knowing which one bounds tigher?
I've tried assuming the $\leq$ bounds tighter, but isn't this a statement? How would this then approach $0$? Otherwise, if $\mathbb{P}(B)$ approaches $0$, how would this be larger than $\mathbb{P}(A)$?
Am I just completely misinterpreting what the statement is supposed to be saying?

Your two events $A,B$ depend on $3$ parameters $d,\delta,n$. The statement means that $P(A)\le P(B)$, and that $P(B)$ tends to $0$ (hence of course, so does $P(A)$) as some parameter(s) tend(s) to I don't know what. Probably $n\to\infty$ but the context is missing. It is also unclear what you mean by "bounds tighter".

Yep I see, so it's not one 'big' statement. Instead, each symbol just connects it's respective left and right parts (if that makes sense). I think I get that now. And sorry, I'm using programming terminology. I meant "bounds tighter" as in precedence. I was thinking of the statement as if it's ambiguous and there needs to be a correct arrangement of brackets around certain parts, but I realize this is an incorrect way of thinking about this.

It really is of the form $\Pr(A_n)\leq\Pr(B_n)\to0$, where $A_n$ and $B_n$ are events depending on $n\in\mathbb N$. All the statement is saying, is that

$\Pr(A_n)\le\Pr(B_n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and
$\Pr(B_n)$ converges to $0$ as a sequence

And the conclusion you are supposed to draw is that since $0\leq\Pr(A_n)\le\Pr(B_n)$ and limit of $0$ and $\Pr(B_n)$ is $0$, by the Sandwich theorem, the limit of $\Pr(A_n)$ as $n\to\infty$ is zero.
Hope this helps. :)

I see, that makes total sense. So, my mistake is trying to think of this as $Pr(A_n)\leq(Pr(B_n)\rightarrow )$ (or another arrangement of the brackets). Instead, I should be getting two different bits of information from each symbol and then combine those to tell me that the probability of event $A_n$ tends to $0$.

@mraya99: Exactly.

Awesome, thanks so much for your help
